# What does element mean here?

Tags: meaning

I was wondering what element means in

> Having survived the elements (both inside and outside) in winter 2023, look forward to get out there.

I can't find a good match in the definition given by Bing. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the text that you quote.  That means title, author, and publication, or as many of those as are available. If the source is long, such as a book, please include a page number or other location also. If the source is online, please include a link also. See [**Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457)

Answer (score 3):

From [dictionary.com...](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/element)

> **elements**
> atmospheric agencies or forces; weather
> *a ruddy complexion from exposure to the elements.*

Note that this sense only ever occurs with the *plural* form - very often as the noun phrase ***exposure to** the elements* or the verb phrase ***brave / face / battle** the elements*. I advise learners *not* to experiment with "similar" alternatives that they haven't actually encountered from native speakers, because they often won't work.

Comment: Thanks. What are "similar" alternatives? Why do they often not work?

Comment: I mean other contexts where ***the elements*** might be used as a reference to "weather". Which hardly exist apart from the examples I gave above (with a few more synonyms for ***brave***, such as ***battle, withstand***). For example, with or without the alliteration, no-one would be likely to say ***The elements in snowy Siberia are harsher than in sunny Spain***. It's a dated "fixed expression" usage that *isn't* used to create new forms today.

Comment: I think elements in the example in my post have also figurative meanings, c.f. "both **inside** and outside".

Comment: Because of "both **inside** and outside", your cited text doesn't really mean *anything* (there is no established concept of "the elements" indoors, and no likely candidate occurs to me). Maybe in context it might be obvious what the writer means, but you haven't provided that.

Comment: I provided everything

Comment: I provided everything

Comment: No - you *haven't* provided either the surrounding text for context that I'm referring to, OR attribution details as requested by David Siegel (that we might use ourselves to access the surrounding text).